# Apploop through events in json feed

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I see a lot of event objects when I use the alert after the ajax post success in my jquery below.

How I can access the details for each event and change them accordingly?

```
eventSources: [
{
    url: 'json-events.php',
    type: 'POST',
    error: function (data) {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!' + data.msge);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        // how do i loop through the event objects and filter which ones are approved == 1?
        if(data.approved == "1") {
            // How do I then change the properties of each event that is approved?
            event.title = title + "approved";
            event.Color = 'green';
            var event.className = "approved";
        } else{
            var event.title = title + "awaiting approval";
            event.Color = 'red';
            var event.className = "unapproved";
        }
    }
}]
```

Update: change color of single event once approved

```
// approve function
$('.approve').click(function (calEvent, jsEvent, view, getid) {
    // Get id of event 
    var getid = $('.approve').attr('id');

    if ($(this).html() == "yes") {
        // AJAX post to insert into DB 
        $.post("ajax.php", {
                action: 'approve',
                color: 'green'
            },
            function (data) {
                var fancyContent = ('<div class="header"><p>' + data.msge + '</p></div>');
                $.fancybox({
                    content: fancyContent
                });
            }, "json");

        // get event 
        var eventObject = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents', getid );

        // set event colors
        eventObject.backgroundColor = 'green';
        eventObject.eventBorderColor = 'green';
        eventObject.title = event.title + " approved";

        // update event somehow?
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', eventObject);
    } else {
        // close fancybox
        $.fancybox.close();
    } // end of  if
}); // end of approve click
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through you JSON response like this:

```
success : function( responseData ) {
  $.each( function( index, responseObj ) {
    if( responseObj.approved === "1" ) {
      responseObj.title += " approved";
      responseObj.className = "approved";
    }
    else {
      responseObj.title += " waiting approval";
      responseObj.className = "unapproved";
    }
  } );

}
```

You will not be able to set the color of each event type using this style of filtering.

You could break up each type into their own event sources, something like:

```
eventSources : [
  {
    url : 'json-events.php?approved=y',
    color : 'green'
    // ... success() and other attributes go here
  },
  {
    url : 'json-events.php?approved=n',
    color : 'red'
    // ... success() and other attributes go here
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. I use an ajax post to approve each event after the user has clicked 'yes' in a fancy box.

If the user clicks 'yes' is there a way I can color the event green? I have updated my code

Many thanks